# vmware in windows 10

Tags: amazon-ec2, hyper-v, vmware-player

I am using Amazon windows 10(2016 server) server for running my application.I need to run VMware in windows but it shows,

**VMware Player and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMware Player.**

I did not install Hyper-V even though VMware is not working, showing above statement.

Comment: Is Hyper-V currently installed on the system?

Answer (score 0):

If Hyper-V is installed you will need to uninstall it for VMWare to run, you can do this by:

```
Press the Windows key + X
Then go to `Programs and Features`
Click Turn Windows Features on or off
Open Hyper-V
Toggle if off and then click okay.
```

Note: you may need to restart the virtual machine afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have followed this step whatever you have mentioned,though its not working.Actually i dont have Hyper-v installed.

Comment: You need to make sure your computer has virtualization enabled. If it's enabled, you will need to uninstall Vmware and install it again.

Comment: virtualization enabled means,i didnt get it.I have tried reinstalling VMware it didnt help

Comment: Please see url for help on how to enable virtualization: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/08/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/

Comment: thank you  but my problem is with vmware,i dont want to install hyper-v.Above i have mentioned that my problem is between vmware and hyper-v and if i try to install hyper-v now, it will lead to clash between them(Iam not sure).

Comment: Ignore the installation of hyper-v, You need to have virtualization enabled for VMware.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with **Amazon EC2**? Are you trying to run VMWare on an Amazon EC2 instance? This is not possible. (If so, why do you "need" it?)

Comment: yes because i could not install torch package in windows. I am facing difficulty so am trying to install a virtual machine in windows EC2 instance

Comment: Was you able to figure this out ?